# Unable to resole Certification Authority endpoint for AWS managedblockchain hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am configuring AWS managed blockchain hyperledger fabric 1.2 network. I have created the network and configured first member. VPC service endpoint is also configured. Now I am on setting up fabric client VM part. I have installed all the necessary packages and components required to setup fabric client ([as mentioned in AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/managementguide/get-started-create-client.html)). But I am unable to verify the Certification Authority (CA) endpoint with the url without `cainfo -k`

> Step 3.2: Set Up the Hyperledger Fabric CA Client

I can curl and use the first url.

```
curl https://CAEndpoint/cainfo -k
```

Below is the response of the above command.

```
{"result":{"CAName":"m-MMMMM","CAChain":"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","Version":"1.2.1-snapshot-"}
```

But unable to execute 2nd url.

```
curl https://CAEndpoint:30002
```

Help me in this regard and point me if I am missing any thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a verification step, to verify that we can connect to the Hyperledger Fabric CA using the VPC endpoint configured in previous steps.

First of all verify and check below things.

- Fabric client (EC2 instance is in same VPC used in creating VPC
  Service endpoint).
- Fabric client (EC2 instance is using same Security Group used in
  creating VPC Service endpoint).
- Port 30001 to 30004 range is allowed in inbound rules in the security
  group.

2ndly there was a mistake in AWS documentation, the 2nd url should be used with telnet, instead of curl.
So instead of below url:

```
curl https://CAEndpoint:30002
```

It must be:

```
telnet https://CAEndpoint:30002
```

This command should show similar to the below result.

```
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to ca.m-MMMMM.n-NNNNNN.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I have already pointed out this mistake to AWS Support and they confirmed that they will update the documentation.

One thing more is that the CA port is not guaranteed to be 30002, but the exact value will be returned in the get-member API.

```
aws managedblockchain get-member --network-id n-NNNNN --member-id m-MMMMM
```

Where m-MMMMM is member-id and n-NNNNN is the network-id.